# How to pass variable from HTML page to nodejs

Tags: html, node.js

I have a requirement where i want to pass variable from HTML to nodejs.Requirement is as below:

1. I have different hyperlink of different areas like Newcastle, Dudley, Belfast.
2. For now i'm calling my nodejs code by passing /Newcastle or /Dudley or /Belfast
3. Now Based on these hyperlink click i'm triggering code to perform process to retrieve data
4. As of now i have seperate processing code for all these
5. What I'm looking to make a single common code to process the above request dynamically.
6. For which I want to pass some variable or parameter from HTML page to node JS to indicate the respective region like Newcastle or Belfast
   Please suggest how I can achieve it.

Comment: Please take a look at ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

If you have:

- ES6
- Express
- URLs like: https://example.com/?city-Newcastle

Then you can do:

```
const { area, city, country, zip } = request.query
```

Full example with query:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/', function(request, result){
   const { area, city, country, zip } = request.query
})

app.listen(3000)
```

Another example with params and ES5:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/:areaID', function(request, result){
  const area = request.params.areaID

  ..whatever code to use that area variable..
})

app.listen(3000)
```

This 2 examples let you extract needed content from URL. After variables and params extracted, you can use them in code as any other variable.

Comment: Hi ValRus, I have posted the details in commnets.. Could you please look and reply.